# HttpHeaders and status value

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot application. I use a rest architecture.

I have this method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/members/card/{cardId}", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
public ResponseEntity hasCardIdValid(@PathVariable(value = "cardId") String cardId) {
    return memberService.hasCardIdValid(cardId) ? new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I another application, I would like to call hasCardIdValid method.
I wrote this code

```
HttpHeaders response = restTemplate.headForHeaders("/rest/members/card/{cardId}", cardId);
```

I don't find a way to get the 200 or 404 value from response. I don't see any method for that.
Is it possible?

Comment: you should to use `exchange` method of RestTemapate. After receive ResponseEntity, call responseEntity.getStatusCode()

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are getting back `HttpHeaders` as a result of your `restTemplate#headForHeaders()` method call.

If you want to get hold of the status you'll have to invoke one of the [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)#exchange() methods instead (there are a few overloaded method signatures) that is giving you back a [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) on which you can invoke [getStatus()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#getStatusCode--).